# Vertical scrolling div over another div, when using fullpage.js

Tags: overflow, jquery-masonry, vertical-scrolling, fullpage.js

I'm looking for a working vertical scrolling solution when placing an additional div over a div (class="section") while using the fullpage.js plugin (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

"overflow: scroll;" for the top-div is not working for me. The top-div is going to be filled with thumbnails sorted via jquery-masonry. Currently all of the thumbnails outside of the 100%-view are hidden, since scrolling is disabled due to a function in fullpage.js.

On top of that when disabling java-script, only the active div is shown. Thus preventing to show all of the divs in descending order.

```
if(options.autoScrolling){
            $('html, body').css({
                'overflow' : 'hidden',
                'height' : '100%'
            });
```

The autoScrolling-option in fullpage.js overwrites the scroll ability of the body css selector.

I could think of an extra div sliding to the top (similar to the one on this page: http://neavebozorgi.com/) with vertical scrolling enabled.

Comment: Could you add a link to your site or reproduce it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  
Have you tried to use the option `scrollOverflow:true`? Another solution could be to use `autoScrolling:false`.

Comment: http://photo.simonschweikert.com/html - I only want the option to be active on a single page/div, like on the example I mentioned (http://neavebozorgi.com/) . `autoScrolling:false` enables scrolling on all pages. In addition the sliding div should be triggered via the top arrow key, which means I need to disable the js-selector from your plugin for this one page. Do you have any advice?

Comment: What you want to achive is done with `scrollOverflow:true` as you can see in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

You are probably initialization in a wrong way your mansonry plugin. Try to do it in the `afterRender` event instead.

Comment: Also, all your scripts should be in the header of the site, not before the `</body>` This might cause problems.

Comment: I would also recommend you to update to the last version of the plugin. 1.4.3, Many bugs has been fixed. The only change it will imply is using `paddingTop` with a measure,  such as `px` or `em`.